# Hibernate retuns object not list

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

When I execute a search using Hibernate I receive

> entities.Tbphonebook@(number and letter combination)

in my console log instead of a list of all items held.  If I change my system out print to

```
system.out.println(person.getLastname)
```

I see what last names are held in the objects that were returned.  I want to search a first name and have first name, Last name, area code, and phone number returned. This may be because I am using depreciated language but I am having a hard time figuring out what the new version should be. I have tried to suppress the warnings but that didn't fix the problem.

Thank you for your help.

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Add contact to Phone Book</title>
    <h1>Add contact to Phone Book</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name="submitInfo" method="get" action="AddEntryServlet">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            Area Code: <input type="number" name="areaCode"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            Phone Number: <input type="number" name="phoneNumber"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
    </body>
    <h1>Search for Contact in Phone Book</h1>
    <body>
      <form name="searchInfo" method="get" action="SearchServlet">
            Search First Name: <input type="text" name="searchFirstName"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            Search Last Name: <input type="text" name="searchLastName"/> <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="search" />
            
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <br>
```

**SQL map file Tbphonebook**

```
    package entities;
// Generated Dec 13, 2017 10:03:41 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.6.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Tbphonebook generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbphonebook", schema = "public")
public class Tbphonebook implements java.io.Serializable {


private int id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Integer areacode;
private Integer phonenumber;

public Tbphonebook() {
}

public Tbphonebook(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Tbphonebook(int id, String firstname, String lastname, Integer areacode, Integer phonenumber) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.areacode = areacode;
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "firstname")
public String getFirstname() {
    return this.firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

@Column(name = "lastname", length = 30)
public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname; 
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Column(name = "areacode")
public Integer getAreacode() {
    return this.areacode;
}

public void setAreacode(Integer areacode) {
    this.areacode = areacode;
}

@Column(name = "phonenumber")
public Integer getPhonenumber() {
    return this.phonenumber;
}

public void setPhonenumber(Integer phonenumber) {
    this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
  }

}
```

**Search Servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import entities.Tbphonebook;
import util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SearchServlet
 */

@WebServlet("/SearchServlet")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SearchServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked" })
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    String firstName = request.getParameter("searchFirstName");
    // String lastName = request.getParameter("searchLastName");

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Tbphonebook where firstname = ?");

    query.setParameter(0, firstName);


    List<Tbphonebook> persons = (List<Tbphonebook>) query.getResultList();


    for(Tbphonebook person : persons)
        System.out.println(person);
    //response.getWriter().append("match" + person);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
  }

}
```

Comment: Tbphonebook should have toString()  to obtain what u want :)

Comment: Thank you adding the toString() in the Tbphonebook file made it all work. I used the eclipse tool to generate a to string and it works as expected. Thank you @Uta Alexandru.